# Is it possible to manage injection of DBContext in separate Layer for Asp.net Core Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, n-tier-architecture

Our asp.net core solution has is separated into the following layers:

**Web UI Projects** (3 different web applications)

**BLL**

**Entities** (Models and View Models)

**DAL** (DBContext, Repositories)

---

All Web UIs will leverage services from the BLL which will in turn reference the DAL to interface with the data. Typically, a service for the DBContext is configured in the startup class.

Is there a way to truly separate this such that the web ui projects do not need to reference the DAL (DBContext) while still using DI? I get it that for dependency injection to occur, the DBContext needs to be configured as a scoped service in startup of the web ui, but logically it does not make any sense to me that the UI needs to reference or have anything to do with the DAL.

Comment: Could do this without dependency injection (i.e. creating a new instance when needed), but wouldn't get the benefit of context pooling.

Comment: Does it really matter if the web project refer to the DAL? The real matter is that your classes are losely coupled between the projects.

Comment: Probably not, just having a hard time accepting the idea that my Web UI needs to reference this and was looking for any possible alternatives. Understanding DI and the composition root a littler more since my post, I get that this has to be managed in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using these layers:

1. Web UI (models with validation attributes- data format, required, etc)
2. Service

   - Contract DLL (interface + entities)
   - Implementation (controller actions)
3. Data Access

Share the contract DLL between the service and the web UI.  Inside the service use whatever DAL / ORM you prefer.  Personally, I prefer [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

Then, generate C# proxies to your JSON service using [Refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit).  Inject Refit proxies into your web controllers via the website's Startup class.  Put most of the business logic in the service controllers and call them from the website controllers.  Keep logic in the website controllers to a minimum.

With this design, the web UI has no knowledge of the data access layer.  You can switch it from Dapper to Entity Framework if you wish.  Refit + a JSON service gives you the benefits of type-safe C# code on both ends (web and service) and the flexibility to write raw HTTP posts when required (say, from AJAX code running in the web browser).

And you can write C# or PowerShell utilities that leverage the service.  In other words, the website need not be the only consumer of the service.

Comment: To clarify, the website, service, and contract are three separate projects within the same Visual Studio solution.  The website and service run on separate endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Despite it's very late, the use case still exists, and here is what I've been doing. I  created a separate extension method in the BAL layer and just called the extension method in the startup.cs or program.cs. In this way, I don't have to refer to the DAL layer in the UI project and the BAL will have the reference for DAL.

BAL > StartUpHelper.cs

```
public static class StartUpServiceRegisterHelper
{
    public static void RegisterDbContext(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, string connectionString)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(option =>
        {
            option.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        });
    }
}
```

UI > Program.cs

```
builder.Services.RegisterDbContext(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection"));
```

Hope it helps.